# writing instead of printing, Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

My code for this works perfectly. I can print to the screen exactly how I want it. However, I want it to write to a file so that I can view the file instead of the print screen.  So I've tried to do the following but I'm coming up with a few issues.  Error message:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import sys
import os, fnmatch


def find_files(directory, pattern):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for basename in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(basename, pattern):
            filename = os.path.join(root, basename)
            yield filename

for filename in find_files('c:/Python27','*file.xml'): 
    print ('Found file.xml:', filename)


xmldoc = minidom.parse(filename)
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Game')
for item in itemlist:
    year = item.getElementsByTagName('Year')
    for s in year:
        print item.attributes['name'].value, s.attributes['value'].value
```

TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given),code with the write function instead:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import sys
import os, fnmatch


def find_files(directory, pattern):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for basename in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(basename, pattern):
            filename = os.path.join(root, basename)
            yield filename
f = open('test.txt','w')
for filename in find_files('c:/Python27','*file.xml'): 
    f.write('Found file.xml:', filename)


xmldoc = minidom.parse(filename)
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Game')
for item in itemlist:
    year = item.getElementsByTagName('Year')
    for s in year:
        f.write (item.attributes['name'].value), f.write(s.attributes['value'].value)
```

Comment: A simple solution without modifying your code is to redirect the stdout to a file. Ex: `python foo.py > output.txt`.

Comment: Oh wow, that would work too!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your two arguments into a single line (that `f.write` will accept) you can do something like

```
f.write("Found file.xml:" + filename + "\n")
```

`+` will concatenate the elements and give you a single string with a newline at the end, for a neat stack of the elements you were looking for in a final file.

As it is, the Error message looks like it's telling you exactly what the problem is -- `f.write` really does take only one argument, and having a comma in the function call indicates a second argument.

Comment: Actually the first error is from the first f.write.  Where the code writes the path name and file.

Comment: Got it, sorry -- same point applies though. `f.write('Found file.xml' + filename)`, no comma. This concatenates the strings, rather than passing them as separate arguments.

Comment: That actually fixed the first one, I might have to work on the second portion. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Terrific! No problem. Good luck,